# Texture loaded and bound, but fragment shader doesn't render it

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to draw a cube with an FBO texture. The texture is rendered to correctly (which I can see in gDebugger), but it doesn't render on the cube. I thought that this might be a problem with the FBO texture so I loaded an ordinary texture and tried it as well, but I get the same problem, just a black cube.

Stepping through the program in gDebugger, I can see that the texture is both loaded correctly and bound, but nothing is drawn. There also doesn't seem to be any problems with the texcoords. Note that I've also tried to output a solid color in the fragment shader which works correctly.

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 420

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 f_texcoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
    f_texcoord = texcoord;
}
```

And this is my fragment shader:

```
#version 420

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 f_texcoord;

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, f_texcoord);
}
```

And this is where I draw the cube:

```c
ShaderManager::Get("world")->Use();
glBindVertexArray(cube_vao);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I must be blind, because I see no errors.

(Also, please note that I am using SFML and GLEW for context creation and extensions.)

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this will be helpful, but this is how I set up the cube VBO, uniforms, etc.:

```c
glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
sf::Image img;
img.LoadFromFile("test.png");
img.FlipVertically();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.GetWidth(), img.GetHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.GetPixelsPtr());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

ShaderTime = 0.0;
camz = -4.0f;
rotation_y = 0.0f;

Shader* shader = ShaderManager::Load("shader", "fx.vert", "fx.frag");
Shader* world = ShaderManager::Load("world", "world.vert", "world.frag");
shader->Use();
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->GetId(), "time"), ShaderTime);
world->Use();
glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)WINDOW_WIDTH / (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, camz));
glm::mat4 model;
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(world->GetId(), "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(world->GetId(), "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(world->GetId(), "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(world->GetId(), "tex"), 0);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &cube_vao);
glBindVertexArray(cube_vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &cube_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_vbo);

GLfloat* data = new GLfloat[5 * 36] {
    // Front
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,      -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    // Back
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,     -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    // Top
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,      -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    // Bottom
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    // Left
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,      -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    // Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,      1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (5 * 36) * sizeof(GLfloat), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (GLvoid*)(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 3));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Do you check the error log when you compile the shader/link the program? The only thing I'm seeing that might be the issue is that variables that start with `gl_` are reserved and the frag shader might be returning an error because of your `gl_FragColor` variable.

Comment: oh yeah, and it doesn't look like you're binding any vertex attributes, so you're not actually drawing anything.

Comment: The drawing is fine, I didn't include the part where I set up my VBO:s, etc. The cube is rendered as it should, but without texturing. As I stated in the question, using gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) successfully renders a red cube. As for the error log, it is empty. I can add the VBO setup if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

===EDIT===

It looks like you're missing the texture setup for the minification filter, which is a problem if you're not using a mipmapped texture. See here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture

Comment: Yes, I do that in my initialization code. I also tried adding it to just before I draw the cube but I get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @Merigrim can you put up all the initialization code? There's nothing in what you've currently got up there that would cause a problem, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Merigrim it looks like you're missing the texture setup for the minification filter, which is a problem if you're not using a mipmapped texture. See here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture

Comment: God, I had no idea that that was required! Adding it solved the problem, thank you so much! If you want to, you could put that in the answer so others can find it easily.